# Stacking each on each on each in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I'm iterating through some `ActiveRecord` models like this:

> (For example sake let's say that you can't directly get all animal
>   genres. It's iterating related question, not association stuff):

```
Animal.all.each do |animal|
    animal.families.each do |family|
        family.genres.each do |genre|
            genre.gsub("o","a")
            genre.save!
        end
    end
end
```

I don't think its the best way to do it. Is there any solution for making it better? Like one iterator that will do `.each` on `each` model?

Comment: If you don't have a need to group the genres by family, why are you nesting the eaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`flat_map`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map):

```
Animal.all.flat_map(&:families).flat_map(&:genres).each do |genre|
  genre.gsub("o","a")
  genre.save!
end
```

(this of course totally ignores any `ActiveRecord` related solutions, which *will* be better)

Answer (score 3):

One way that will speed this up, is try to do all the queries first.

```
animals = Animal.includes(families: genres)
animals.each do |animal|
  animal.families.each do |family|
    family.genres.each do |genre|
      genre.gsub("o","a")
      genre.save!
    end
  end
end
```